# How to get an object with matches count based on two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

how to get object based on two arrays, where the values in the first are unique, and in the second any, where the key will be a word, and the value is the number of matches of this word?

For example: 
`let uniqueArray = ['green', 'blue', 'red'];` 
`let anyArray = ['red', 'green', 'red', 'blue, 'yellow', 'green', 'pink', 'red'];` 
We get: 
`{'green': 2, 'blue': 1, 'red': 3}`

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think the question is very clear. Is there a relationship between the first and the second array? If so, how come `red` is returned?

Comment: @Cerbrus I have tried different combinations using .map, .filter and .reduce, but none of them worked as expected.

Comment: Please expand your question with some attempts, so we can get an idea of what you're actually trying to do, and what those arrays mean.

Comment: @thinkgruen my bad, edited the arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to count occurrences in `anyArray` of entries in `uniqueArray`.

You can do this using a `reduce`:

```js
let uniqueArray = ['green', 'blue', 'red'];
let anyArray = ['red', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'pink', 'red'];

const result = uniqueArray.reduce((data, key) => {
  data[key] = anyArray.filter(x => x === key).length;
  return data;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```